# Real and imaginary part of tensors of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$, clearly we can write $A=\Re(A)+i \Im(A)$, i.e., the real and imaginary part of $A$. (For instance, $A=[1,i]$, then $A=[1,0]+i[0,1]$).

I am interested in the tensor of $A$, $A^{\otimes d}$. It is not difficult to see that $\Re(A^{\otimes d})$ and $\Im(A^{\otimes d})$ can be written as expressions of $\Re(A)$ and $\Im(A)$. For example, $\Re(A^{\otimes 2})= \Re(A)\otimes \Re(A)-\Im(A)\otimes \Im(A)$, and  $\Im(A^{\otimes 2})= \Re(A)\otimes \Im(A)+\Im(A)\otimes \Re(A)$. However, for higher $d$, the expression gets rather involved.

I am wondering whether there is a general theory regarding this. For instance, is there sort of compact form for $\Re(A^{\otimes d})$ and $\Im(A^{\otimes d})$?
Any results, guidance, reference are highly appreciated.